# Access nativeView of a Label

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I need to limit the max number of lines of a Label with ellipsis overflow.

With NativeScript core, this would work.

```
var label = page.getViewById("label");

if (label.ios) {
    label.ios.numberOfLines = 2;
    label.ios.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail;
} else if (label.android) {
    label.android.setMaxLines(2);
    label.android.setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
}
```

But this doesn't work with vue, since `ios` always return `undefined`, no matter what.

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Label ref="label" text="A big text"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            let label = this.$refs.label; // works.

            //label.nativeView          <- works.
            //label.nativeView.ios      <- undefined.
            //label.nativeView.android  <- undefined.

            //It's weird, because if I list the keys of nativeView, the 'ios' property is present...
            for (let key in label.nativeView) {
                console.log(key);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tested this using iphone 6 plus, iOS 12.1.2. I don't have an android device to test, I don't know if the result would be as expected.

Playground link with NativeScript Core [HERE](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=Jf4eSf).

Playground link with NativeScript-Vue [HERE](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=CGKHOx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not Vue but when exactly you are accessing your native view. The native view may not be ready when the component is mounted. Either use the `loaded` event of `Page` like you do in Core or use the `loaded` event of the `Label` itself which guarantees that the native view is created.

**Update:** I have updated your [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=CGKHOx&v=2).